# Printer adding script, can't specify default port

Tags: vbscript, port, printers

```
@echo off
REM --------------------------------------------------------KC 122 MFP

echo Installing KC 122 MFP
cscript C:\Windows\System32\Printing_Admin_Scripts\en-US\Prnport.vbs -a -r IP_192.168.100.20 -h 192.168.100.20 -o raw -n 9100
rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /ia /m "KONICA MINOLTA Universal PCL" /f "\\Server\Printer Drivers\Konica-Minolta\350-250-200-MFP\Win_x64\KOB__J__.inf"
rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /if /b "KC 122 MFP" /f "\\Server\Printer Drivers\Konica-Minolta\350-250-200-MFP\Win_x64\KOB__J__.inf" /r "IP_192.168.100.20" /m "KONICA MINOLTA Universal PCL"
RUNDLL32 PRINTUI.DLL,PrintUIEntry /y /n "KC 122 MFP" 192.168.100.20
Pause
```

The above works but won't specify a default port. I have to do it manually. I'm trying to script it but can't seem to get it to work.

I have tried several variations of the folowing:

```
cscript C:\Windows\System32\Printing_Admin_Scripts\en-US\Prnmngr.vbs -p "KC 122 MFP" -r
```

It only returns the Arguments and Examples...

I tried uttering the magical phrase "Printicus Installio"...that also failed.

Comment: `PRNCNFG.vbs` configure a printer.

Comment: `cscript C:\Windows\System32\Printing_Admin_Scripts\en-US\Prncnfg.vbs -p "KC 122 MFP" -r IP_192.168.100.20`

Thanks JosefZ, the above code still only gives me the Arguments and Examples as if I entered the command wrong. I must be missing something. I'm only trying to specify the port name and/or IP for printer KC 122 MFP. Any ideas?

Comment: Add `-t` argument of meaning _set configuration_ as follows: `... prncnfg.vbs -t -p "KC 122 MFP" -r IP_192.168.100.20`. For more info try `... prncnfg.vbs -?` or `/?`, or read the script in a [good text and code editor](http://www.pspad.com/en/)

Comment: That was it! Thanks JosefZ! How do I mark this as answered?

Answer (score 0):

`prncnfg.vbs` - printer configuration script for `WMI` on *Whistler* (i.e. Microsoft code name for Windows XP) used to get and set printer configuration also used to rename a printer. Usage (not complete):

```
[cscript] [path\]prncnfg[.vbs] { -g | -t | -x | -? } ...
```

or

```
[cscript] [path\]prncnfg[.vbs] { /g | /t | /x | /? } ...
```

Main switches:

- `-g` Display configuration information about a printer
- `-t` Configure a printer
- `-x` Change the name of a printer
- `/?` (optional) Usage hints

Your task should be accomplished by (path to script omitted):

```
cscript prncnfg.vbs -t -p "KC 122 MFP" -r IP_192.168.100.20
```